# Understanding a measure space $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ and the relationship between $\mu$ and $\mathcal{M}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

I have a tough time understanding measure spaces equipped with a set $X$, a sigma-algebra $\mathcal{M}$ and a measure $\mu$, particularly the connection between measurable sets and the sigma-algebra $\mathcal{M}$. Please correct my understanding here, if I am wrong: sigma-algebras generate the set $X$ and any subset of $X$ is measurable if and only if it is an element of the sigma-algebra $\mathcal{M}$. Thus, for example, the Vitali set is not measurable when $\mu$ denotes the Lebesgue measure and $X=\mathbb{R}$. However, the Vitali set could be measurable if, say we define $\mu$ as the counting measure and $X=\mathbb{R}$. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No, it is wrong: a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ that satisfy [some properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra). The $\mathcal{M}$-measurable sets are *defined* as the sets in $\mathcal{M}$.

Comment: Ideally, we wouldn’t need $\sigma-$algebras. We need them because, for some $X$ we can’t get a $\mu$ defined on all of $\mathcal P(X),$ all subsets of $X.$ So in those cases, we have to take some subset of $\mathcal P(X).$ The conditions on $M$ are set to let us do all the operations we need to do. So it is always worth remembering that $M$ is a “hack” to get around the problems that arise with certain measures, like the standard measure on $\mathbb R.$

Comment: It’s not clear what you mean by “generates $X.$” Usually, $X$ is defined first, and then $M.$ A $\sigma-$algebra is defined “on a set $X.$”

Comment: But is it true that if a subset of $X$ is measurable, it is in the sigma-algebra $\mathcal{M}$?

Answer (score 2):

You are right that the counting measure makes all subsets of $\mathbb R$ measurable. This is true for the counting function for any $X.$

We could still use some $M$ other than $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$ for the counting measure, but we usually pick the largest $M$ which makes sense for the particular measure.

But different measures on the same set can use different $\sigma-$algebras.

The usual approach to defining a measure space is we start with a set $X,$ and an idea for the values of $\mu$ some subsets of $X.$ Then we try to expand $\mu$ to as many sets as we can, and that collection of sets becomes our $M.$

So, the Lebesgue measure $\mu_L$ starts with the “obvious” $\mu_L((a,b))=b-a.$ The counting measure starts with $\mu_c(\{x\})=1.$

---

In theory, the smallest $M$ to work with $\mu_c$ is:

$$M=\{S\subseteq X\mid S \text{ or }X\setminus S\text{ is countable}\}$$

That’s an inadequately small $M,$ but it gives a sense how limited $M$ can be and still be a $\sigma-$algebra.

---

It’s worth thinking of $\sigma-$algebras as a “hack.” The ideal would be for $M$ to always be $\mathcal P(X).$ Unfortunately, we have to use something else in some cases, because there are examples like the Vitali set which cannot be measured, so we sometimes take $M\subsetneq \mathcal P(X)$ of measurable sets that is smaller than the ideal $\mathcal P(X).$

We have conditions on these measurable sets, the $\sigma-$algebra conditions, to make sure we can do all the things we’d want with them.

So $M$ must be closed under countable unions, because a condition on $\mu$ is that it is countably additive.  But the conditions do not require closure under arbitrary unions, because then we’d get Vitali-like examples.

Basically, we had a problem: We can’t define our measure on all of $\mathcal P(X)$ in some cases. The solution was to find something “close enough” to $\mathcal P(X)$ to be usable.

---

Amusingly, in constructive math, it can be proved all sets in $\mathbb R$ are measurable (and all functions are continuous.) Essentially, Vitali sets and the like are an outcome of the non-constructive Axiom of Choice.

Answer (score 0):

You start with a set $X$ and a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{M}$ of sets that you want to be able to measure. For Lebesgue measure this is the Borel algebra (the $\sigma$-algebra generated by all open sets, or alternatively all $[a,b)$ sets etc.).

Next you can consider measures that have $\mathcal{M}$ as domain, Lebesgue measure being one for the Borel sets (determined by $\mu([a,b))= b-a$ etc.).

We could also have started with all subsets of $\Bbb R$ as the starting set of measurable sets ($\mathscr{P}(\Bbb R)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra too) and then there are options like the counting measure and atomic Dirac measures like $\delta_x(A) = 1$ is $x \in A$ and $0$ otherwise. It’s undecidable whether there is a finite measure on all subsets that is $0$ on all singletons (the real-valued measure problem, for sure not if CH holds e.g.), or even a $\sigma$-finite one that extends the Lebesgue measure.

Interestingly enough we can extend the Lebesgue measure from just the Borel sets to a larger class which is then called confusingly Lebesgue measurable sets (using null sets e.g.), so that Lebesgue measure then measures more than the continuum many Borel sets, but as many (cardinalitywise) as the power set; see Caratheodory’s extension theorem etc.) but still sets can be shown to exist  that cannot be measured (i.e. added in a consistent way to the basic Lebesgue measurable ones), using AC.

So the measurable sets are just the preferred domain for measures on $X$. It’s usually not the measure we start with. Different measures will have different natural domains as it were.